# Kafka Acknowledgment vs Kafka commit

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

What is the difference between Kafka Acknowledgment and Kafka consumer commitSync ()

Both are used for purpose of manual offset management, and hope both works Synchronously.

Please assist

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When using spring-kafka, the `Acknowledgment` is an abstraction over the detailed consumer API for committing offsets.

When you call `acknowledgement.acknowledge()`; the action depends on configuration. With `AckMode.MANUAL`, the commit is queued for the consumer to process later; with `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE`, `commitSync()` (default, or async, depending on configuration) is called immediately.

Comment: Thanks Gary for quick response, got it so MANUAL_IMMEDIATE and commitSync does the same stuff..Acknowledgment is a more of a spring way to manage offsets